# JavaScript code(JQuery) not display in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display chart in view in rails app. use this link http://jsfiddle.net/zz7pB/ contain chart

in `application.html.erb` and try it in view

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

in `application.js`

```
//= require_tree 
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require chart   ---> name of controller
```

`chart.js` in `app -> assets -> javascripts`

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

in `index.html.erb`

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

i want display this chart in my app this all information. This live chart

when inspect element display  `div`  put not contain `chart`.

i read this [Where should I place my jQuery code in my Ruby on Rails applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371303/where-should-i-place-my-jquery-code-in-my-ruby-on-rails-applications) but not solve it

This error appear in the console in the browser 
[image]

Comment: in `application.js` you have only 5 lines ?

Comment: no  contain `//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require highcharts
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//=require plugins/highcharts
//=require plugins/exporting
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require gmaps/google
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts
//= require fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint`

Comment: do u have extra JS files in `assets/js` folder that not mentioned in `application .js` file ?

Comment: channels but empty?

Comment: did u figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**:
**Step 1**

I created a new rails application and, [Jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) Gem added to the Gemfile.

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
```

`application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And then run `bundle install`
**Step 2**
Downloaded [HighchartJs](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js) and [ExportingJs](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js) files and placed in `assets/javascripts/plugins` folder. And, These libraries are imported to `application.js` as below.
`application.js`

```
//= require plugins/highcharts
//= require plugins/exporting
```

**Step 3**
Created `chart.js` file and imported to `application.js`

```
//= require chart
```

Then paste your Js code in this file. All should work now.
**Tips** Please follow more tutorials to learn how to debug javascript with browser console.

[image: application.js]
[image]

Comment: how  to pass hash data to highcharts-rails Gem

Comment: No. This gem will only provide you the library files. But Still you have to use your custom js file as it is. But you don't need to download and place library files inside your App. First try my first answer rather using this gem.

Comment: i try your answer `chart.js` inside `app-assets-javascript-plugins` show this error and try `vender/assets/javasript ` show this error   `couldn't find file 'plugins' with type 'application/javascript'`

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my answer. Create a folder called plugins in `vender/assets/javasript` or `app/assets/javascript` and paste both downloaded highcharts.js and exporting.js files in here.

Comment: i download highcharts.js  but how download exporting.js . i search but not can

Comment: Thanks you but not appear. store  highcharts.js and exporting.js in vender/assets/javasript or app/assets/javascript

Comment: Thank you but i walk all step but not appear and upload photo of console in question ?