# Using Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my Rails 6 project, I have been trying to use the asset pipeline to get `application.js` to use jQuery and a JavaScript file at `app/assets/javascript/event_index.js`, but neither are working. I am getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` when I load my web page, and my JavaScript code is not doing anything when I click on things.

Things I have tried:

- The top answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371303/where-should-i-place-my-jquery-code-in-my-ruby-on-rails-applications) suggests that I can just write `//=require events_index` to get events_index.js, but this isn't doing anything
- I didn't realize that my `//= require` lines have to be in the header. When I changed that, it still didn't help
- I ran `gem 'jquery-rails'`
- I was using `$(document).ready()` previously, but apparently because Rails 6 uses TurboLinks, this doesn't work anymore, so I changed it

Here is the full text of my application.js file:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require events_index

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [This article](https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/introducing-jquery-in-rails-6-using-webpacker) ended up being helpful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 6 comes with webpacker by default, you should instead install jquery via yarn and load it via webpacker. See [How to add jquery third party plugin in rails 6 webpacker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905026/how-to-add-jquery-third-party-plugin-in-rails-6-webpacker)